# Advice on connecting this light to a ceiling rose

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling

I have bought a vintage light but i'm not sure how to attach it to my ceiling. I currently have a regular ceiling rose (UK) but I can see I need to replace that with something else. Just not sure what.

[image]

Comment: You might post a photo of your "regular ceiling rose". I've done a lot of wiring and fabrication, but I can't picture what that means.

Comment: @isherwood I believe the tag you're looking for is "UK".

Comment: can that cup shaped par be moved down the shaft?